# MySQL match and insert functions

Tags: mysql

I'm new in MySQL, need help. I have two tables. First:

```
Moscow, RU
Paris, FR
Shanghai, CN
```

Second:

```
1, Mocow, RU
2, Saint-Petersburg, RU
3, London, GB
```

I need to find matches by cityname and countrycode and if there is no city in Second table I need to INSERT new line (number is auto_increment). For example second table will continues as:

```
4, Paris, FR
5, Shanghai, CN
```

Many thanks for help!

Comment: you want to do that with only mysql?

Comment: @JoshKisb Python script will add these lines into table and rut this function. So I can do it one by one. But much better, as for me to give more job to DB, but have a lack of knowlage.

Comment: Any indexes on these tables and have you tried insert on duplicate key https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `[cityname, countrycode]` a unique composite key such that if a query tries to add another row with same cityname and country code combination, a duplicate key error occurs

After making them unique you can simply use [INSERT IGNORE](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-ignore/)

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `tableB`(`cityname`, `countrycode`) VALUES 
('Moscow', 'RU'),
('Paris', 'FR'),
('Shanghai', 'CN')
```